# Date and Time not updating when a custom attribute is updated

Tags: product, product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.2.3

We're running **Magento ver 2.2.3** on one of our sites and noticed that t**he date and time aren't being updated** when making a change **to a custom attribute**. I tried looking online but haven't found an answer. Does anyone know if this is a known issue or something? Has anyone ever ran into this same problem before? Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The issue we were running into was that the updated_at timestamp wasn't updating when editing the Supplier of a product. Because the Supplier field is a custom attribute, we thought that might be where to begin looking.

But we ran tests today, updating the Supplier of both Simple and Customizable products, and the updated_at field successfully updated each time. I'm not sure what has changed on our end since creating this thread, but the problem seems to be resolved now.